# Restrict user from adding some Active Directory DLs to SharePoint Site Permissions?

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint-2013

Is there any way to restrict a user from adding some specific Active directory DLs to SharePoint - 2013 Site permissions?

Does SharePoint fire an event while adding users/DLs to group, for which an event receiver can be written?

Or can it be achieved using SharePoint's App Model?

If not, please suggest me on how to achieve it either using code or using configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can restrict people picker to only certain organisation units from Active Directory either on farm level or on zone level. Please have a look on [msdn](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg602075%28v=office.15%29.aspx) and specifically on [Peoplepicker-distributionlistsearchdomains](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c95da957-8eeb-4312-b039-7ac5c0f89a7e%28office.12%29.aspx)